# Filtering mysql data in a table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I created a function to show my data from the mysql database into a simple table and it works fine. The only problem is that I need to filter out the results which have value 1 for the "bot" column and show all the other rows. (The value is only 1 when the useragent shows its a bot).

It sort of seems to work but instead of no showing the whole row it just changes every single value in the "bot" column to a 0.

```
if(isset($_POST['togglebots'])){
    $sqlselect = "SELECT * FROM `page_load` WHERE `bot` = 0";
}else{
    $sqlselect = "SELECT * FROM page_load";
}
```

So when the checkbox is enabled it will only who the rows which have a value of 0 for the "bot" column. Or atleast thats what it is supposed to do, instead it changes all the values to a 0 and shows everything anyway lol

The code I use to generate the table is this:

```
if ($resultselect->num_rows > 0) {

    echo '<div style="margin:10px;"><table style="padding:10px">';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultselect, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
        $temp = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',$row['firsttime']);
        $temp2 = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',$row['lasttime']);

        echo '
            <tr >
                <td style="padding:6px;  border: 1px solid black;">ID: </td>
                <td style="padding:6px;  border: 1px solid black;"> ' . $row['id'] . '   </td>
                <td style="padding:6px;  border: 1px solid black;">Useragent:</td>
                <td style="padding:6px;  border: 1px solid black;"> ' . $row['useragent'] . '   </td>
                <td style="padding:6px;  border: 1px solid black;">REMOTE ADDR:</td>
                <td style="padding:6px;  border: 1px solid black;"> ' . $row['ip_address'] . ' </td>
                <td style="padding:6px;  border: 1px solid black;">TAG: </td>
                <td style="padding:6px;  border: 1px solid black;">' . $row['tag'] . ' </td>
                <td style="padding:6px;  border: 1px solid black;">BOT: </td>
                <td style="padding:6px;  border: 1px solid black;">' . $row['bot'] . ' </td>
                <td style="padding:6px;  border: 1px solid black;">First reload:  </td>
                <td style="padding:6px;  border: 1px solid black;">' . $temp . ' </td>
                <td style="padding:6px;  border: 1px solid black;">Last reload: </td>
                <td style="padding:6px;  border: 1px solid black;">' . $temp2 . '</td>
                <td style="padding:6px;  border: 1px solid black;">Total reloads: </td>
                <td style="padding:6px;  border: 1px solid black;">' . $row['totalreloads'] . '</td>
            </tr>';

    }
        echo '</table></div>';
} else {
        echo "<p>0 results</p></table></div>";
}
```

It runs through all the results and adds the values to a new row in the table. If there are no results it simple outputs "0 results".

EDIT: [full page source code](http://pastebin.com/HR3fPfKT)

Comment: so what you want to do is display all row that bot = 0 if toggled and all row that bot = 1 if not ?

Comment: if the toggle is on it should only show rows where bot = 0

Comment: Can we see your form? Because this doesnt seem to be true: `isset($_POST['togglebots'])`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HR3fPfKT here is the full page, ill updated the main page aswell

Comment: can you see what contain your togglebots var in both case ?

Comment: do you have any records with 0 under bot column?

Comment: the value is either 1 if it is considered a bot or 0 if it isn't, it can't be a null